# Moving a function in a running thread to a new thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, function, qthread

I have a read and write function in a class file. this class subclasses `QThread` class and overrides run, **does not have signals and slots ,It basically runs data processing functions in a thread**. in its constructor is the method `movetothread(this)`. To have the two functions to form a queue and implement muli-threading , 
can i make a `movetothread(secondthread)` call in the write function?

```
void write(args)
{
 movetothread(secondthread);
}
```

to make the write function run on a separate thread. 
How and when does the write function stop?.

Comment: i had found http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.general/38137 regarding the movetothread(this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work that way. `QObject::moveToThread` associates the *object* with another thread, not the calling function. Furthermore, this affects future event processing only.

Comment: ok so calling it in the class constructor would associate it with the object of the class and that is why movetothread(this) in constructor works?

Comment: No, do read the article that `zvezdi` linked. Threading in Qt isn't intuitive.

Comment: I have read that already... can you answer my question to your post?. i have a class without signals n slots like in the example in that blog post. i had assumed since the constructor used movetothread(this)  we can do something like that to a function. i have read the documentation for the function http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/qobject.html#moveToThread .

Comment: Well, as the article spells out, it is very likely that the `moveToThread(this)` in the constructor doesn't work, either. Without slots, what event are you going to process ? And without events, why are you telling Qt which thread to use for event processing?

Comment: the class is used to read to buffer and then write to disk. this is was previously a single write to disk thread. look at post 50 of that article... can you tell me what you understand by using movetothread(this) in constructor???

Comment: Yes, I understand that it is wrong. When you subclass `QThread`, you do so to override `QThread::run()`. This gives you one (1) thread. Your question assumes you have two (2) threads. That means you must have two QThread objects somewhere.

Comment: I presume the right/wrong part is based on the old vs new version qt libraries you are working with .My question indicates i am trying to create a second thread to execute the write function in the first thread .

Comment: There are two distinct ways to use `QThread` and both are right; mixing is wrong. If you need a second thread, create a second QThread object. Make sure it calls the write function (using either of the 2 correct methods). But if thw write function is in the first thread, it is _not_ in the second thread. A function call is an unmodifiable part of the call stack, which is a property of each thread.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. i think this is the answer i am looking for . can you give brief pusedocode/example of these two distinct ways.It would really be most useful and appreciated.

Comment: @AdityaGameProgrammer: the end of a long line of comments would be a bad place. Make it a new question instead, if you invest a few minutes you could get quite some votes for it :) .